# Page templates: jQuery Mobile or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, json, templates

This might be a very basic question, but I'm getting a bit confused. I'm working on a small web app which is based on 3-5 pages, mostly list based, with a couple pages being based on a single "object" of some data. I want to create basic templates for these pages and fill them with data from my database. I'm using jQuery Mobile.

My question is - if I use some method of retrieving the data via JSON, which is better? I guess it would be like this:

[image]

**Edit:** As a third option, what if I did this: index.php gets the json from data.php and just outputs it as a JSON object, which I can use jQuery to fill the data into the page, and then only use getJSON if that object isn't defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 is really your best bet from a separation of concerns perspective. If you ever decide to change your backend implementation (i.e.: RoR or ASP.NET for example), you should not need to change your client-side code.

Option 1 will indeed give you a marginal performance benefit over Option 2, and is a good option if you **KNOW** that the backend implementation will never change.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go with number 1.

### Reasoning:

1. The client will need to send extra requests the get the data it needs. Rather then the server fetching it for itself.

And that's about it really, but it's a very strong argument :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a page that loads with the data already on it. Some people disable JavaScript in their browser, and then they wouldn't be loading the data.

Comment: I don't think I need to worry about javascript being disabled for this project. This is a web-app intended for mobile devices based on jQuery mobile for fun/educational purposes. For future reference, I'll definitely keep this in mind.